# ASP.NET Core create a view get error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I try generate a view for my controller, but i get error.

```html
>Method not found: 'void'
>Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Desing.Internal.DbContextOperation.ctor
>{Microsoft.EntityFrameWorkCore.Design.Internal.IoperationReporter,
>System.Reflection.Assembly, System.Reflection.Assembly}
```

and

[image: Error picture]

and this is all my dependences untill now

[image: Dependences picutre]

when i try update Microsoft.AspNetCore.All to 2.1.2 get this error:
[error when try update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDHiE.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should update the NuGet package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` to the latest version (2.1.2).